# OpenXml SDK PowerPoint Sunburst chart

Tags: c#, excel, office365, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

The Sunburst chart type was introduced in Office 2016 / 365, along with some other new chart types. I'm trying to work with the chart type in PowerPoint, but it can also be created in Excel, for example. (Excel provides the charting engine for all Office applications.)

Sunburst seems to be stored differently from other charts, the Productivity Tool doesn't seem to detect it normally and there seems to be an image representation of the chart instead of the actual chart data itself. The Productivity Tool shows no XML and the reflected code resembles the below

```
// Generates content of extendedPart1.
private void GenerateExtendedPart1Content(ExtendedPart extendedPart1)
{
    System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(extendedPart1Data);
    extendedPart1.FeedData(data);
    data.Close();
}
```

which streams in binary information, for example

```
    #region Binary Data
    private string partData = "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACslMtOwzAQRfdI/EPkLUrcskAINe2CxxIqUT7AxJPGqmNbnmlp/56J+xBCoRVqN7ESz9x7MvHNaLJubbaCiMa7UgyLgcjAVV4bNy/Fx+wlvxcZknJaWe+gFBtAMRlfX41mmwCYcbfDUjRE4UFKrBpoFRY+gOOd2sdWEd/GuQyqWqg5yNvB4E5W3hE4yqnTEOPRE9RqaSl7XvPjLUkEiyJ73BZ2XqVQIVhTKWJSuXL6l0u+cyi4M9VgYwLeMIaQvQ7dzt8Gu743Hk00GrKpivSqWsaQayu/fFx8er8ojov0UPq6NhVoXy1bnkCBIYLS2ABQa4u0Fq0ybs99xD8Vo0zL8MIg3fsl4RMcxN8bZLqej5BkThgibSzgpceeRE85NyqCfqfIybg4wE/tYxx8bqbRB+QERfj/FPYR6brzwEIQycAhJH2H7eDI6Tt77NDlW4Pu8ZbpfzL+BgAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAtVUwI/QAAABMAgAACwAIAl9yZWxzLy5yZWxzIKIEAiigAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKySTU/DMAyG70j8h8j31d2QEEJLd0FIuyFUfoBJ3A+1jaMkG92/JxwQVBqDA0d/vX78ytvdPI3qyCH24jSsixIUOyO2d62Gl/pxdQcqJnKWRnGs4cQRdtX11faZR0p5KHa9jyqruKihS8nfI0bT8USxEM8uVxoJE6UchhY9mYFaxk1Z3mL4rgHVQlPtrYawtzeg6pPPm3/XlqbpDT+IOUzs0pkVyHNiZ9mufMhsIfX5GlVTaDlpsGKecjoieV9kbMDzRJu/E/18LU6cyFIiNBL4Ms9HxyWg9X9atDTxy515xDcJw6vI8MmCix+o3gEAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAOgRAAEYAwAANAcAAA8AAAB4bC93b3JrYm9vay54bWysVV1vmzwUvp/0/gfkexebrwAqmUIArdI6TWvXXU4umMYqYGRMk67af98xCem6TlO0vVFi5/gcP+c5HxzO3+7axnrgahCySxA9I8jiXSkr0d0l6PN1gUNkDZp1FWtkxxP0yAf0dvnfm/OtVPe3Ut5bANANCdpo3ce2PZQb3rLhTPa8A00tVcs0iOrOHnrFWTVsONdtYzuEBHbLRIf2CLE6BUPWtSh5Jsux5Z3egyjeMA30h43ohxmtLU+Ba5m6H3tcyrYHiFvRCP04gSKrLeOLu04qdttA2DvqWzsF3wB+lMDizJ5A9cpVK0olB1nrM4C296RfxU+JTemLFOxe5+A0JM9W/EGYGh5ZqeAvWQVHrOAZjJJ/RqPQWlOvxJC8v0Tzj9wctDyvRcNv9q1rsb7/wFpTqQZZDRt0XgnNqwQtQJRb/uJAjX06iga0juOTENnLYzt/VFbFazY2+hoaeYaHJyMIIsc3ljsVz8n+qJUF/y+y9+Dwij2AewiyOnTnBeBT8rUrVUwJIV+fVmEY0CxMceHmIfYWKw+vojzDYUo9d12s8oiS75AkFcSlZKPeHIIz6Any/N+oLtlu1lASj6J6ZvIEPqcPNusvy6z7biIyj/GN4NvhOQ1GtHZfRFfJbYL8BYG4HmfRBWE7qb6ISm9MlBRyczh7x8XdBvi6rrkEtTa0EvTkkNQtfIfixaJwsEcyB0e+s8JBnnoLPwvp2okmOvZPfKZpAbym3eqmCl+ZCUJhLJl9SjKyVGx8qIuKmoDs+VrJmhIqarbJEBLsRMZCNvxKfONQvTpBq+kS3+n3g16ew26NSgBj6pHVgkQeJrnrYy+MHBx6roPXXubk/iLP8tQ39TIDMP4/xgA0F/XjebIa4hum9LVi5T3M40+8TtkAPbaPEXj+TDb1w5S4QNEraIE9GhGcpoGH/axw/QXN1rlfPJM1GYHIfxnapw2b0J5uc6ZHBW8DID3JsVmLw+nxsN4fHEr3wkH8KZuep/3tPxleQfQNP9G4uDnRcP3h8vpyapffBmBPCTbr1Bb2XJblDwAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAIE+lJfzAAAAugIAABoACAF4bC9fcmVscy93b3JrYm9vay54bWwucmVscyCiBAEooAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKxSTUvEMBC9C/6HMHebdhUR2XQvIuxV6w8IybQp2yYhM3703xsqul1Y1ksvA2+Gee/Nx3b3NQ7iAxP1wSuoihIEehNs7zsFb83zzQMIYu2tHoJHBRMS7Orrq+0LDppzE7k+ksgsnhQ45vgoJRmHo6YiRPS50oY0as4wdTJqc9Adyk1Z3su05ID6hFPsrYK0t7cgmilm5f+5Q9v2Bp+CeR/R8xkJSTwNeQDR6NQhK/jBRfYI8rz8Zk15zmvBo/oM5RyrSx6qNT18hnQgh8hHH38pknPlopm7Ve/hdEL7yim/2/Isy/TvZuTJx9XfAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA++YwKnYDAADGDQAAGAAAAHhsL3dvcmtzaGVldHMvc2hlZXQxLnhtbJyXXY+iMBSG7zfZ/0C4VygifkSdqIzZudhks1/3FYuSAUra6sxks/99TyFCW5YJTDImg+/p24eentO6enjNUutGGE9ovrbR2LUtkkf0lOTntf3r52E0ty0ucH7CKc3J2n4j3H7YfP60eqHsmV8IERY45HxtX4Qolo7DowvJMB/TguSgxJRlWMAjOzu8YASfykFZ6niuGzgZTnK7cliyPh40jpOIhDS6ZiQXlQkjKRbAzy9Jwe9uWdTHLsPs+VqMIpoVYHFM0kS8laa2lUXLp3NOGT6m8N6vyMeR9crgz4PP5D5N+X1rpiyJGOU0FmNwdirm9usvnIWDo9qp/f69bJDvMHJLZAIbK+9jSGhae3mN2eSDZkFtJpeLLa/JaW3/QYfD4wLtgtEuDLyRjx790c7z5iM3mB7C3WQaHLazv/ZmdUogw/KtLEbitb1FyxDNbGezKjfQ74S8cOV/S+DjD5KSSBCYBNmW3J9HSp9l4BN85cqhTmvsodyf35h1IjG+puI7fflCkvNFgIk/9qYALjO/PL2FhEew5cBp7E9rjhALvFkx+mJB+mBaXmBZDGjpd43crCIZG0IwmHF409vGXTk3oIvgA1a1H+Sgt98Wgms/VPuVc+1UzdO1vapNdC30SjqvGaLhQVb740FwJ56qmXiq5ht4kxIPdeBBBvrjQXAnnqqZeKo2NfD8Cm/+/+TC1uqPB8GdeKoWGMlVtZmBNy3x5s3XWnKDIXgQ3ImnaiaeqjXLVNVHUOF1rN5sCB4Ed+Kp2sJYoVmVwI4Vkidj32rfQnAngqY1raBahnnF0Gx9LUuLIQwQ3DCYLUITzV2uiWaTWFRNotn9GiGCG0X/ZZLR3Yy6anYDUGUvRc0m00GGdOctUtszMhdLV4263+uqsedDUCWm15FRNKjpy+h31ktTW5iaanYHcJaY86Ym9NUc1PyR1v2NSt/pqlGEe031zPIA9d2kDzoEkHYKtDA1tYWpnRLGhgnBucTsWs1BhwHSToMWpqoqR3fZTvbaWM8sZVDLpHeV0KBDAWmnQgtTVduYmtqq9OpsUPD1vTnocIBLpVJCLUxV9cwTHsaWtdykuwKp7pnV3bDAZ/IVs3OScyslcXmBBFNWXTLdsZyAFvJaOYPMHakQNLs/XeD3EoHLojuGAoopFfcHeZetf4Ft/gEAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAMEXEL5OBwAAxiAAABMAAAB4bC90aGVtZS90aGVtZTEueG1s7FnNixs3FL8X+j8Mc3f8NeOPJd7gz2yT3SRknZQctbbsUVYzMpK8GxMCJTn1UiikpZdCbz2U0kADDb30jwkktOkf0SfN2COt5SSbbEpadg2LR/69p6f3nn5683Tx0r2YekeYC8KSll++UPI9nIzYmCTTln9rOCg0fE9IlIwRZQlu+Qss/Evbn35yEW3JCMfYA/lEbKGWH0k52yoWxQiGkbjAZjiB3yaMx0jCI58Wxxwdg96YFiulUq0YI5L4XoJiUHt9MiEj7A2VSn97qbxP4TGRQg2MKN9XqrElobHjw7JCiIXoUu4dIdryYZ4xOx7ie9L3KBISfmj5Jf3nF7cvFtFWJkTlBllDbqD/MrlMYHxY0XPy6cFq0iAIg1p7pV8DqFzH9ev9Wr+20qcBaDSClaa22DrrlW6QYQ1Q+tWhu1fvVcsW3tBfXbO5HaqPhdegVH+whh8MuuBFC69BKT5cw4edZqdn69egFF9bw9dL7V5Qt/RrUERJcriGLoW1ane52hVkwuiOE94Mg0G9kinPUZANq+xSU0xYIjflWozuMj4AgAJSJEniycUMT9AIsriLKDngxNsl0wgSb4YSJmC4VCkNSlX4rz6B/qYjirYwMqSVXWCJWBtS9nhixMlMtvwroNU3IC+ePXv+8Onzh789f/To+cNfsrm1KktuByVTU+7Vj1///f0X3l+//vDq8Tfp1CfxwsS//PnLl7//8Tr1sOLcFS++ffLy6ZMX333150+PHdrbHB2Y8CGJsfCu4WPvJothgQ778QE/ncQwQsSSQBHodqjuy8gCXlsg6sJ1sO3C2xxYxgW8PL9r2bof8bkkjpmvRrEF3GOMdhh3OuCqmsvw8HCeTN2T87mJu4nQkWvuLkqsAPfnM6BX4lLZjbBl5g2KEommOMHSU7+xQ4wdq7tDiOXXPTLiTLCJ9O4Qr4OI0yVDcmAlUi60Q2KIy8JlIITa8s3eba/DqGvVPXxkI2FbIOowfoip5cbLaC5R7FI5RDE1Hb6LZOQycn/BRyauLyREeoop8/pjLIRL5jqH9RpBvwoM4w77Hl3ENpJLcujSuYsYM5E9dtiNUDxz2kySyMR+Jg4hRZF3g0kXfI/ZO0Q9QxxQsjHctwm2wv1mIrgF5GqalCeI+mXOHbG8jJm9Hxd0grCLZdo8tti1zYkzOzrzqZXauxhTdIzGGHu3PnNY0GEzy+e50VciYJUd7EqsK8jOVfWcYAFlkqpr1ilylwgrZffxlG2wZ29xgngWKIkR36T5GkTdSl045ZxUep2ODk3gNQLlH+SL0ynXBegwkru/SeuNCFlnl3oW7nxdcCt+b7PHYF/ePe2+BBl8ahkg9rf2zRBRa4I8YYYICgwX3YKIFf5cRJ2rWmzulJvYmzYPAxRGVr0Tk+SNxc+Jsif8d8oedwFzBgWPW/H7lDqbKGXnRIGzCfcfLGt6aJ7cwHCSrHPWeVVzXtX4//uqZtNePq9lzmuZ81rG9fb1QWqZvHyByibv8uieT7yx5TMhlO7LBcW7Qnd9BLzRjAcwqNtRuie5agHOIviaNZgs3JQjLeNxJj8nMtqP0AxaQ2XdwJyKTPVUeDMmoGOkh3UrFZ/QrftO83iPjdNOZ7msupqpCwWS+XgpXI1Dl0qm6Fo9796t1Ot+6FR3WZcGKNnTGGFMZhtRdRhRXw5CFF5nhF7ZmVjRdFjRUOqXoVpGceUKMG0VFXjl9uBFveWHQdpBhmYclOdjFae0mbyMrgrOmUZ6kzOpmQFQYi8zII90U9m6cXlqdWmqvUWkLSOMdLONMNIwghfhLDvNlvtZxrqZh9QyT7liuRtyM+qNDxFrRSInuIEmJlPQxDtu+bVqCLcqIzRr+RPoGMPXeAa5I9RbF6JTuHYZSZ5u+HdhlhkXsodElDpck07KBjGRmHuUxC1fLX+VDTTRHKJtK1eAED5a45pAKx+bcRB0O8h4MsEjaYbdGFGeTh+B4VOucP6qxd8drCTZHMK9H42PvQM65zcRpFhYLysHjomAi4Ny6s0xgZuwFZHl+XfiYMpo17yK0jmUjiM6i1B2ophknsI1ia7M0U8rHxhP2ZrBoesuPJiqA/a9T903H9XKcwZp5memxSrq1HST6Yc75A2r8kPUsiqlbv1OLXKuay65DhLVeUq84dR9iwPBMC2fzDJNWbxOw4qzs1HbtDMsCAxP1Db4bXVGOD3xric/yJ3MWnVALOtKnfj6yty81WYHd4E8enB/OKdS6FBCb5cjKPrSG8iUNmCL3JNZjQjfvDknLf9+KWwH3UrYLZQaYb8QVINSoRG2q4V2GFbL/bBc6nUqD+BgkVFcDtPr+gFcYdBFdmmvx9cu7uPlLc2FEYuLTF/MF7Xh+uK+XNl8ce8RIJ37tcqgWW12aoVmtT0oBL1Oo9Ds1jqFXq1b7w163bDRHDzwvSMNDtrVblDrNwq1crdbCGolZX6jWagHlUo7qLcb/aD9ICtjYOUpfWS+APdqu7b/AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAeaGAbKQCAABSBgAADQAAAHhsL3N0eWxlcy54bWykVW1r2zAQ/j7YfxD67sp24ywJtsvS1FDoxqAd7Ktiy4moXowkZ87G/vtOdl4cOrbRfolO59Nzz91zUtKbTgq0Y8ZyrTIcXYUYMVXqiqtNhr8+FcEMI+uoqqjQimV4zyy+yd+/S63bC/a4ZcwhgFA2w1vnmgUhttwySe2VbpiCL7U2kjrYmg2xjWG0sv6QFCQOwymRlCs8ICxk+T8gkprntglKLRvq+JoL7vY9FkayXNxvlDZ0LYBqF01oibpoamLUmWOS3vsij+Sl0VbX7gpwia5rXrKXdOdkTmh5RgLk1yFFCQnji9o780qkCTFsx718OE9rrZxFpW6VAzGBqG/B4lnp76rwn7xziMpT+wPtqABPhEmellpogxxIB53rPYpKNkTcUsHXhvuwmkou9oM79o5e7UOc5NB77ySex2GxcIgLcWIVewLgyFOQzzGjCtigg/20byC9gkkbYPq4f0RvDN1HcTI6QPqEebrWpoLJPvfj6MpTwWoHRA3fbP3qdAO/a+0cqJ+nFacbrajwpQwgJwPKKZkQj376v9UX2F2NVCsL6e6rDMM98k04mlDIwRzwho3HH6MN2G+GRV19iQ+II9oXpE/pkdc7w5/9dRUwOQcItG65cFz9gTBgVt25BaFXwPmr1zfnlAU6UbGatsI9nT5m+Gx/YhVvZXyK+sJ32vUQGT7bD16paOpzsM49WBgvWFFreIZ/3i0/zFd3RRzMwuUsmFyzJJgny1WQTG6Xq1UxD+Pw9tfoAXjD9e/fqzyFi7WwAh4Jcyj2UOLj2Zfh0Wag388o0B5zn8fT8GMShUFxHUbBZEpnwWx6nQRFEsWr6WR5lxTJiHvyymciJFE0PDiefLJwXDLB1VGro0JjL4gE278UQY5KkPOfQf4bAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCdyM0K/AAAAOwCAAAUAAAAeGwvc2hhcmVkU3RyaW5ncy54bWx0ksFOwzAQRO9I/IPlO3Uc2lCQ40ogceJW+AAr2TaW4nXwOgj+npBeULM5+nk9OzOyOXyHXnxBIh+xlnpTSAHYxNbjuZYf7693eykoO2xdHxFq+QMkD/b2xhBlMb1FqmWX8/CkFDUdBEebOABON6eYgsvTMZ0VDQlcSx1ADr0qi6JSwXmUookj5lpud1KM6D9HeLmAspLWkLcm2yMkD6SNytaoP3TBz8lh04kFP2YIS/oG7rRCy2vlefb+ms66/OyWVdixtGLpw0q6xb7ZxcLb7HjPKj+yOXjHumAl9Fr3fEd8bs1Xp3kNviW9Yntl4z8RNf1W+wsAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAFTmubJBAQAAawIAABEACAFkb2NQcm9wcy9jb3JlLnhtbCCiBAEooAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJSSX0vDMBTF3wW/Q8l7m7ZjU0LbgZM9ORCcKL6F5G4LNn9Iol2/vWm71ep88TE55/5yziXF8ijr6BOsE1qVKEtSFIFimgu1L9Hzdh3fosh5qjittYISteDQsrq+KpghTFt4tNqA9QJcFEjKEWZKdPDeEIwdO4CkLgkOFcSdtpL6cLR7bCh7p3vAeZousARPOfUUd8DYjER0QnI2Is2HrXsAZxhqkKC8w1mS4W+vByvdnwO9MnFK4VsTOp3iTtmcDeLoPjoxGpumSZpZHyPkz/Dr5uGprxoL1e2KAaoKzgizQL221Uoo3kYbEC4kKPBE6bZYU+c3YeE7Afyu/W2+NARyX2TAA49CNDIUOSsvs9X9do2qPM3TOM3ifLHN5iS/JfP8rXv/x3wXdbiQpxT/It5MiGdAVeCL71F9AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAYUkJEIkBAAARAwAAEAAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWwgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACckkFv2zAMhe8D+h8M3Rs53VAMgaxiSFf0sGEBkrZnTaZjobIkiKyR7NePttHU2XrqjeR7ePpESd0cOl/0kNHFUInlohQFBBtrF/aVeNjdXX4VBZIJtfExQCWOgOJGX3xSmxwTZHKABUcErERLlFZSom2hM7hgObDSxNwZ4jbvZWwaZ+E22pcOAsmrsryWcCAINdSX6RQopsRVTx8NraMd+PBxd0wMrNW3lLyzhviW+qezOWJsqPh+sOCVnIuK6bZgX7Kjoy6VnLdqa42HNQfrxngEJd8G6h7MsLSNcRm16mnVg6WYC3R/eG1XovhtEAacSvQmOxOIsQbb1Iy1T0hZP8X8jC0AoZJsmIZjOffOa/dFL0cDF+fGIWACYeEccefIA/5qNibTO8TLOfHIMPFOONuBbzpzzjdemU/6J3sdu2TCkYVT9cOFZ3xIu3hrCF7XeT5U29ZkqPkFTus+DdQ9bzL7IWTdmrCH+tXzvzA8/uP0w/XyelF+LvldZzMl3/6y/gsAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAYu6daF4BAACQBAAAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC1VTAj9AAAAEwCAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJcDAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDoEQABGAMAADQHAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALwGAAB4bC93b3JrYm9vay54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAgT6Ul/MAAAC6AgAAGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABCgAAeGwvX3JlbHMvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA++YwKnYDAADGDQAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0DAAAeGwvd29ya3NoZWV0cy9zaGVldDEueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAMEXEL5OBwAAxiAAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4A8AAHhsL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAeaGAbKQCAABSBgAADQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABfFwAAeGwvc3R5bGVzLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQCdyM0K/AAAAOwCAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4aAAB4bC9zaGFyZWRTdHJpbmdzLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQBU5rmyQQEAAGsCAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFwbAABkb2NQcm9wcy9jb3JlLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQBhSQkQiQEAABEDAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANQdAABkb2NQcm9wcy9hcHAueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAKAAoAgAIAAJMgAAAAAA==";
```

Is it possibly to generate a Sunburst Chart in PowerPoint using OpenXML SDK in C#?

Comment: What is the origin of this chart?

Comment: @CindyMeister not sure what do you mean? It is a chart type in powerpoint.

Comment: @CindyMeister yes, it was you and 2 other people initially, the mod only changed it after I flagged the question for help, but it seems he too thought I am not worthy of having my question up on SO.

Comment: It has nothing to do with you, personally, being "worthy" (or not). The problem is that the question doesn't contain enough information - my vote was that it's was unclear without additional information. I don't know what others were thinking. For example, you didn't specify PowerPoint nor the version of Office involved. I'd never heard of a Sunburst chart type, before - turns out it was introduced in Office 2016. I'm going to edit in the relevant information so that this can go into the re-open queue.

Comment: I've located what's going on, and will post that in an Answer when/if the question is re-opened as it's (currently, anyway) important for Office Open XML. The reason the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool doesn't produce anything useful is because these are new charts. There's a new version of the tool that can work with these: http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/release-of-preview-of-the-open-xml-sdk-v3-0/

Comment: This blog post mentions that the Productivity Tool hasn't been updated yet. Also, I cannot find the branch it mentions, and version 3.0 of Open XML SDK does not exist anywhere, not sure what this is about.

Comment: Did you read the information on the GitHub link, in its entirety?

Comment: Well it would seem version 2.10 released just 2 weeks ago added some "initial support" for Office 2016, including ExtendedChartPart, but I found nothing specific on Sunburst and how I would go about implementing it using ExtendedChartPart.

Answer (score 0):

Adding charts to a presentation using Open XML SDK is very time consuming. If you were to use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), you would add a Sunburst chart like this:

```cs
using var presentation = new Presentation();

// Add an empty Sunburst chart to the first slide.
var chart = presentation.Slides[0].Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.Sunburst, 20, 20, 500, 400);
chart.ChartData.Categories.Clear();
chart.ChartData.Series.Clear();

var wb = chart.ChartData.ChartDataWorkbook;
wb.Clear(0);

// Branch 1:
var leaf = chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C1", "Leaf1"));
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(1, "Stem1");
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(2, "Branch1");

chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C2", "Leaf2"));

leaf = chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C3", "Leaf3"));
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(1, "Stem2");

chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C4", "Leaf4"));

// Branch 2:
leaf = chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C5", "Leaf5"));
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(1, "Stem3");
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(2, "Branch2");

chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C6", "Leaf6"));

leaf = chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C7", "Leaf7"));
leaf.GroupingLevels.SetGroupingItem(1, "Stem4");

chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(wb.GetCell(0, "C8", "Leaf8"));

var series = chart.ChartData.Series.Add(ChartType.Sunburst);
series.Labels.DefaultDataLabelFormat.ShowCategoryName = true;
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D1", 4));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D2", 5));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D3", 3));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D4", 6));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D5", 9));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D6", 9));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D7", 4));
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForSunburstSeries(wb.GetCell(0, "D8", 3));

presentation.Save("Sunburst.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

Result:

[image]

This is a paid library, but you can get a temporary license to evaluate all features. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.